Unity, Camera movement Tilt
Trying to add a camera tilt while moving. Found this code in forums posted by "bididon0" yet in my particular case, I assume, it only works partially. As long as I do not rotate my player the left and right tilt works fine, but the second I turn 90* the tilt changes direction to up and down.
public Transform camHolder;

float xRotation;
float yRotation;

public float _tiltAmount = 5;
public float _rotationSpeed = 0.5f;

void Start()
{
 
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Tilt();
    
}

public void Tilt()
{
    float rotZ = -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * _tiltAmount;

    Quaternion finalRot = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, rotZ);
    camHolder.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(camHolder.transform.localRotation, finalRot, _rotationSpeed);
}

I assume the problem is with my set up, since I have a camHolder that this script referencing a transform of and it does not rotate or follow my camera rotation, but I'm not sure. It seems the solution is literal one piece of syntax since its partially working, but I'm new to this so I wouldn't even know where to look or how. Its also a rigidbody controller if that's important and this is the reason for camHolder since that's the only solution I found to prevent camera jitter. If somehow I can make a cam holder rotate along the horizontal axis to follow the camera rotation or change that up and down rotation to left and right on all axis. Also, I though of integrating this tilt into main cameraLook script, which probably would've been the best solution, but it seems like twice as hard to do and it be nice to have this tilt function be separate like that regradless. Please help.

i heavily recommend you to use cinemachine. but for you problem here, i believe you are rotating you main player object. usually it is better to have an appearance object as child of your player and do rotations on that so your other codes dont get confused. rotations in unity are a little complicated and after years of developing unity games, i still don't understand it
